# Render Text in React JS

Tags: reactjs, text

How do I render text in React JS? I am new to react and I wanted to know how to render Text in ReactJS

My code is looking something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import './app-style.css';



function HomePage() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
                <div className="front_logo">
                </div>
            <div className="arrange-frontText">
                <p>The easy way to save time and money, wherever you shop</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    );
}

export default HomePage;
```

And my CSS looks like this

```
.App {
    text-align: center;
  }

.front_logo{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden; 
    left:82px;
    top:0px; 
    width:1185px; 
    height:158px; 
    z-index:0;
    background: url('1col_ShortHeader_cg_1500x200._CB435957986_.png') no-repeat center;
}

.shout-text{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

.arrange-frontText{
    text-align: center;
}
```

I want to Render this text **"The easy way to save time and money, wherever you shop"**

Comment: The code looks fine. Can you explain a little more about the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Please Look at the screenshot , I edited

Comment: There is no screenshot. Please recheck.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any issues in your code and it is rendering correctly. If your desired styling is not rendered properly then just remove the `<p>` tag like so

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="front_logo"></div>
      <div className="arrange-frontText">
        The easy way to save time and money, wherever you shop
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I am not getting your question then please elaborate your issue in the comments or you may even edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.

I ended up building the Application using Webpage Maker then rendering it with React. Rendering the  tags in the return()

Thanks everyone!